# `leaps` package in R still exists? or is it under a new name?

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I'm attempting to install the `R` package `leaps`. I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary, just a simple package installation, but it appears the package doesn't exist or can't be found.

```
> install.packages(leaps)
Error in install.packages : object 'leaps' not found
```

I was wondering if this is a new issue? I'm installing using R Studio on a PC for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
install.packages("leaps")
```

As an explanation, this is quoting the name of the package, as it doesn't exist as a variable in your workspace. To further confuse things, non-standard evaluation in R lets you sometimes use unquoted column names (eg in `ggplot`), but this is not one of those times.

Comment: tried it same issue...I take that back...it worked :)

Comment: It looks to me like the package still exists https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/index.html

Comment: yes...all the documentation I found it online, but entering it the way I did for some reason didn't work....oh well got it up and running now. thanks for the help